# Error in writing excel docs with python

Tags: python, excel

I am writing a program to fetch a bunch of data from the web then write it in an excel document. In the last step I am getting an error while trying to write the cells and I am not sure what the error means or what I could do to fix it.

The error looks like this:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write
self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 235, in write
self.__adjust_bound_col_idx(col)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 78, in __adjust_bound_col_idx
raise ValueError("column index (%r) not an int in range(256)" % arg)
ValueError: column index (256) not an int in range(256)
149-166-202-213:Peter peter$`
```

The error is supposedly on line 106, which is blank. It seems like I am trying to write to cells that are not within the range of the document, how could I extend the range of the excel document or change the way I'm writing to the cells to help?

BTW, the modules I'm using to access excel docs are [here](http://python-excel.org)

Comment: range(256) goes from 0 to 255; you're trying to write to the 256th indexed column which is actually the 257th column, and are thus getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of columns in a `.xls` spreadsheet is 256 ([according to Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)). If you go to the Excel 2010 format, that limit is [increased to 16,384](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291).

---

From some (rather brief) research, it looks like [OpenPyXL](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) might work for you. I can't find any hard-coded column limits in its code or docs, and unfortunately I don't have a version of Excel to test it for you, but it certainly looks promising.

Comment: right. I found [this package](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) which works with `.xlsx` files from 2007, I'm trying to see what their cols limit is...

Comment: then maybe my problem is that I'm trying to put the columns and rows in the wrong place, because I believe I should only have 2 columns but around 1000 rows. I must have mixed up the (x, y). Thanks!

Comment: Now xlwt supports writing to .xlsx files. @MattDMo you may update this answer

Answer (score 0):

you have too many columns it(an excel worksheet) only supports 256 columns and 65k ish rows